# About installing packages in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management

My machine is not an Internet connected. So I mounted the ISO image and installed some packages. If I want to INSTALL GDB and some other packages how should I install in the machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can download most ubuntu packages from this [sight.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdb) Download form a connected machine and copy to usb/dvd etc. 
and then install them using the terminal command [dpkg](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php) 
The catch is you'll have to make sure that all dependencies are met. Which can be very time consuming.  It would be much better to find a way to connect the machine at least temporarily to the internet.